# Do I need a Schengen transit visa if I am transiting in 2 different Schengen countries?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit-visas, schengen-visas

I know this question has been asked but my situation is a bit different. I am going to Malaysia via Amsterdam on the outbound flight and returning via CDG (Paris) on the return flight from Malaysia. As I am transiting in 2 different countries on international legs, will an airport transit visa be ok for both legs or will I need to get a regular Schengen C type visa?

Answer (score 4):

Since you won't be on any **Schengen-internal flight**, what you have is just two independent transits. If you need an airport transit visa for one or both of these transits, a single visa (with a sufficiently long period of validity) will be enough for both transits.

Comment: Airport transit visas have limited validity, there one-way and return ATVs, but I believe they are country specific, so OP would need to get one ATV from each country (if that country requires it).